# How to yield all elements on each depth level of BST?

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree, yield

I am trying to create generator which will give me values from next depth level of BST. Let's say that our tree will look like:

[image: BST Example]

I would like to get result for following code like:

```
for level in tree:
    print(level)
# 3
# (1,5)
# (2,4,7)
```

I was testing different variations of `yield` usage, but none of them gave me expected result. Here is code which I ended with:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, element):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = element

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.data
        if self.left and self.right:
            yield from self.left.__iter__() and self.right.__iter__()
        elif self.left:
            yield from self.left.__iter__()
        elif self.right:
            yield from self.right.__iter__()
        else:
            pass

    def add_element(self, element):
        if self.data > element:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = Node(element)
            else:
                self.left.add_element(element)
        else:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = Node(element)
            else:
                self.right.add_element(element)

    def get_structure(self):
        return (self.left.get_structure() if self.left else None, self.data, self.right.get_structure() if self.right else None)
```

This is given example from top:

```
from node import *

tree = Node(3)
tree.add_element(5)
tree.add_element(1)
tree.add_element(2)
tree.add_element(4)
tree.add_element(7)

print('Structure:',tree.get_structure())        #result: (None, 1, (None, 2, None)), 3, ((None, 4, None), 5, (None, 7, None)))
print('Iteration:', end=" ")                    #reslut: 3 5 7 / expected result: 3 (1,5) (2,4,7)
for level in tree:
    print(level, end=" ")
```

Explain me please how can I fix my `__iter__` method to get values from each depth level of tree?

Comment: I don't' think possible because ask is not to follow link but get  level values, 
Obviously you could do it without yield , but that's not ask.

I would like to see answer too ;)